# How to prevent multi value dictionary object from splitting each word into individual letter strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a dictionary object that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {123456789123: ('a', 'category'),
           123456789456:('bc','subcategory'),123456789678:('c_d','subcategory')}
```

The below code extracts and compares a integer in column headers in a df to the key in the dictionary and creates a new dataframe by picking the second value as the columns of the new df and first value as the value inside the df.

Code:

```
names = df.columns.values
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for name in names:    
    if ('.value.' in name) and df[name][0]:
        last_number = int(name[-13:])
        print(last_number)
        key, value = my_dict[last_number]
        try:
            new_df[value][0] = list(new_df[value][0]) + [key]
        except:
            new_df[value] = [key]
```

new_df:

```
   category                subcategory
0    a                     [b, c, c_d]
```

I am not sure what is causing it in my code, but how do I prevent `bc`from split up?

edit:

example df from above:

```
data.value.123456789123    data.value.123456789456     data.value.123456789678   
    TRUE                      TRUE                        TRUE
```

new_df should look like this:

```
   category                subcategory
0    a                     [bc, c_d]
```

Comment: `list(new_df[value][0])` breaks a string into a list of characters. `list(new_df[value][0])` must be `[new_df[value][0]]`. Or, better, `list(new_df[value][0]) + [key]` must be `[new_df[value][0], key]`.

Comment: `[new_df[value][0], key]` this worked! I will accept if you answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list(new_df[value][0])` breaks a string into a list of characters, that's why you get the individual characters.

`list(new_df[value][0])` must be `[new_df[value][0]]`. Or, better, `list(new_df[value][0]) + [key]` must be `[new_df[value][0], key]`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DataFrame` constructor and `groupby`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.values()))
df.groupby(1)[0].apply(list).to_frame(0).T
1 category subcategory
0      [a]   [bc, c_d]
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the OP wants `['bc', 'c_d']`: "_How do I prevent `bc` from split up?_"

Comment: @W-B I am not following where I will integrate your line of code and why I am converting the dictionary obejct to a df? I added an edit with an example df I am working with.